# Optimizing a SQL query for SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a database with 8 tables out of which I need to be able to search for a specific value in 6 of them.

The query, in short, should do something like this:

```
SELECT i.InActivity,
   i.ReceivedTime,
   i.ReceivedFrom,
   i.DataSize,
   o.FileName,
   o.FileSize,
   o.Status,
   s1.UniqueReference,
   s1.SenderCode,
   s1.ReceiverCode,
   s2.DetailId,
   s3.UnitDescription,
   t1.SenderCode,
   t1.ReceiverCode,
   t2.TaskDescription,
   t3.TaskStatus
FROM InData i
LEFT JOIN OutData o WITH(NOLOCK) ON i.ActivityID = o.InActivity
LEFT JOIN SupplyDataLevel1 s1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON s1.InActivity = i.ActivityID
LEFT JOIN SupplyDataLevel2 s2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON s2.ParentId = s1.ActivityID
LEFT JOIN SupplyDataLevel3 s3 WITH(NOLOCK) ON s3.ParentId = s2.ActivityID
LEFT JOIN TasksDataLevel1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON t1.InActivity = i.ActivityID
LEFT JOIN TasksDataLevel2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON t2.ParentId = t1.ActivityID
LEFT JOIN TasksDataLevel3 t3 WITH(NOLOCK) ON t3.ParentId = t2.ActivityID
WHERE s1.IdSender = @searchParam OR
      s1.IdReceiver = @searchParam OR
  s2.StackNumber = @searchParam OR
  s2.StackOrderNumber = @searchParam OR
  s3.Reference = @searchParam OR
  t1.ProcessReference = @searchParam OR
  t1.ProcessStage = @searchParam OR
  t1.MasterNumber = @searchParam OR
  t2.ProcessStep = @searchParam OR
  t3.SubProcessStep = @searchParam
```

So question is, there has to be a better way than this. The tables contains millions of rows and executing this query will, no doubt, take hours and hours to execute, which rhymes badly with the web site which will have the search page.

Should I create a view and query that one, would that be a better alternative, performance wise?

Any help is welcome.